# Hide used source port in TCP with XDP(eBPF) from different network namespace

Tags: c, tcp, packet, ebpf, xdp-bpf

I have topology with 2 network namespaces and one veth pair with one in each namespace. Let's call namespaces `server` and `client`. I want to run 2 process in each namespace which will communicate with each other via TCP but server process will not know the client's real port number. Want to load XDP(eBPF) program which will change the source and destination port number in TCP header on the client's side. Are the packet's sent in client's namespace processed in client's eBPF program (process packets on arrival) ?  Is it possible to implement it or I would need more complex topology with the bridge?

Comment: Why do you want to use XDP instead of TC as the hook point? If you attach to a veth you won't benefit from the performance boost anyway.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to perform SNAT and reverse SNAT on the client's traffic, but keeping the source IP untouched (only changing the client's port). Why do you want to use eBPF instead of e.g. iptables to do this?

Comment: I want to present the capabilities of the XDP, what your suggestion will be?

Comment: If you want to demo what XDP can do, I would suggest to use the BPF samples present in the Linux sources: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/samples/bpf/README.rst.

Comment: I don't want existing demo, just want to know if it is possible

Comment: Sure. Yes, it's possible, as outlined above. It's "just" a matter of implementing SNAT and reverse SNAT at the XDP hook of the veth device. Iptables allows you to do that out of the box though.